# Date Format in MYSQL with Timezone

Tags: mysql

I have to display below date like 27-Apr-2015 in mysql
Monday 27 April 2015 12:12:36

How to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Abu

Comment: Date is Monday 27 April 2015 12:12:36 PM IST

Comment: You should not perform date formatting in SQL because it's a view-layer concern - it also burdens the consumer with needing parse the date back. Instead you should return date values from a database as an actual `date` or `datetime` value, not as text.

Answer (score 3):

**Try This:-**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('27 April 2015 12:12:36', '%d %M %Y %h:%i:%S'), "%d-%b-%Y");
```

First you need to convert your string to date. then you can format the same.

if your date like **Monday 27 April 2015 12:12:36 PM IST**
 **use:**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('Monday 27 April 2015 12:12:36 PM', '%W %d %M %Y %h:%i:%S %p'), "%d-%b-%Y");
```

Hope this help !

Comment: your welcome , if it helped you can accept the answer , Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL DATE_FORMAT Function](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date_format/) is there to rescue.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(yourDateColumn,'%W %d %M %Y %T') `Date`
FROM yourTable;
```

See a [**DEMO on SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04f960e/1).

Answer (score -2):

Try this variant

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%d-%M-%Y");
```

This will output

```
02-March-2018
```

Or if you want shorter month name, use %b instead %M

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%d-%b-%Y");
```

More information you can find [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)